# Problema al generar PDF con DOMPDF

Tags: php, mysql, dompdf

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```
<?php

    require_once("../../../VISTA/conexion.php");
    require_once '../../../FRAMEWORKS/dompdf-master/lib/html5lib/Parser.php';
    require_once '../../../FRAMEWORKS/dompdf-master/src/Autoloader.php';

    Dompdf\Autoloader::register();


$codigoHTML ='<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>


<div> 

        <center>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
              <tr>
                <th>ID</th>

                </tr>
              ';       


               $sql = "SELECT * from socios;";
               $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

               while($filas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
                $d = $filas["idsocio"];
               $codigoHTML .='<tr><td>'.$d.'</td></tr>';
               }
              $codigoHTML .='

            </table>
        </center>                        
</div>
</body>
</html>';





//reference the Dompdf namespace

use Dompdf\Dompdf;

$codigoHTML=utf8_encode($codigoHTML);
// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml($codigoHTML);

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->set_paper('A4', 'portrait');
//Cambiando la fuente
$dompdf->set_option('defaultFont', 'Courier');

// Convertir the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();
// Descargar el PDF generado
$dompdf->stream("Reporte_usuarios.pdf");

 ?>
```

Con este código trabajando localmente no me genera ningún error me genera el pdf correctamente pero cuando lo subo a hostinger me arroja server internal error, y no me genera ningún pdf, ahora bien quitando  la parte de la consulta a la base de datos me lo genera correctamente, alguna idea de porque sucede esto ?

Comment: ¿Sale algún error en los logs?

Comment: No marca ningún error mas que el estado 500 "internal server error"

Comment: Verifica la configuración de las rutas en el servidor, probablemente no estén habilitadas para rutas relativas.

Comment: El error 500 regularmente se relaciona con un error dentro de un include, por asi decir, mientras llamas a Dompdf.php, se genero algun error de consulta o alguna variable no definida, va a cortar el codigo y mandara error 500

Comment: me pasa exactamente lo mismo.. al subir al hosting no me genera los PDF.